# Is the sequence of Riemann integrals monotone?

Tags: analysis

Let f : [0,1] → R be a bounded function. Let $P_n = {x_0, x_1,..., x_n}$ be a uniform partition of [0,1], that is, xj := j/n. Is the sequence $\{L(P_n ,f)\}$ as n goes from 1 to $\infty$ always monotone? Yes/No: Prove or find a counterexample.

Intuitively I think the sequence should be monotone increasing as a more refined partition will give larger values to multiply by in the lower darboux sums.. But how do I prove this rigorously? I cannot think of a counterexample either so I think I'm right...

Comment: Is \{L(P_n ,f)$ the left sum or the lower sum? As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Some_specific_types_of_Riemann_sums

Comment: Lower Darboux Sum on function f with partition P

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the function $f(x)=1$ on $[0, 0.5]$ and $f(x)=0$ on $(0.5, 1]$. The lower sum is $0.5$ for $n=2$ and $1/3$ for $n=3$.

Comment: Let me just add that the lower darboux sum is indeed monotone, provided that every partition is finer than the precedent, which is obviously no the case if one chooses the uniform partition, as your example shows

Comment: looks like I didn't think hard enough! Thanks.

Comment: To add to Caffeine's comment: the problem is indeed that you do not only add a new point to your partition, you also move points that were already there, whenever you increase $n$.