# Behavior of $L(U,f)$ on a uniform partition

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question on this problem asked about here:

[Is the sequence of Riemann integrals monotone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628843/is-the-sequence-of-riemann-integrals-monotone)

I am having trouble seeing how the counterexample presented in the answer actually disproves the statement. For example, I calculated for the lower sum at $n = 2$ to be $\frac{1}{4}$, not $\frac{1}{2}$ (as shown in the answer):

$$L(P,f) = \sum^2_{i=1} m_i \Delta x_i = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

At least for the calculation of the first few cases, the particular example presented in the answer does appear to generate a monotone sequence for $\{L(P,f)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ (specifically monotonically increasing). What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know where you're getting your $m_i$s from, but I read them as $1$ and $0$ respectively, giving $\frac{1}{2}$ as claimed in the question.

Comment: The sequence $L(f, P_n) $ is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing if $P_{n} \subseteq P_{n+1}$. But if we don't have successive refinement of partitions the sequence of lower sums may not be monotone. In particular if $P_n$ represents the division of the interval into $2^n$ subintervals of equal length then the refinement condition holds and lower sum is increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=2$, then $x_0=0, x_1=\frac12, x_2=1$.

$$f=\begin{cases} 1, & x \in [0, \frac12] \\ 0 &, x \in (\frac12, 1]\end{cases}$$

Hence $m_1 = f(0)=1$, $m_2 = 0$.

$$L(P_2, f)=\sum_{i=1}^2  \frac{m_i}n =\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^2 m_i = \frac12 (1+0) = \frac12$$

I can't see where do you get the other $\frac12$ since $f$ only takes values $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong. I was inserting the $x$ value into $m_1$, rather than looking at the function value within that particular interval to get $m_1$. So then at this point once you establish that $L(P_2,f) = \frac{1}{2}$ and that $L(P_3,f) = \frac{1}{3}$, it shows that the sequence is not monotone.